# Regex to match prices with different digit

Tags: regex, go, expression, regex-greedy

I am trying to write a regex with go to match prices that composed by at least five digits with comma on the price.

For example:

"10,400,000","10,900,000","500,000",

I was trying the following expression: "((\d+)(,)(\d+))(,)..."(,) which matches only for the sequence that has eight digits (two commas).

For example:

```
"10,400,000", valid
"10,900,000", valid
"500,000", invalid
```

I don't think it would be efficient if I process it twice (one for the number with two commas and the other with one comma). how can I make the expression for the whole pattern?

Thank u

Comment: What about `\b(?|\d?\d?\d(?:,?\d\d\d)+,?\d\d\d|\d?\d\d,?\d\d\d)\b`  https://regex101.com/r/RgoXzl/1

Comment: I assume `"10,400,000","10,900,000","500,000",` refers to three separate strings, and not to a single string (delimited by single quotes, say) that contains double-quotes as well as digits and commas. If so, I suggest you place each string on a separate line.

Comment: @Jerry, your regex matches `"00,000"`, `"10,000"` in `"10,000,00"` and `"100,000"` in `",100,000"`.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that we need to either match a number between 10,000 and 999,999 or a number 1,000,000 or larger, with commas in the right places.

To match a number between 10,000 and 999,999 we can use

```
^[1-9]\d{1,2},\d{3}$
```

and to match a number 1,000,000 or larger we can use

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,}$
```

We therefore merely need to construct an alternation comprised of these two expressions.

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{1,2},\d{3}|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sNq2MY/1)

---

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^          # match beginning of the string
(?:        # non-capture group
  [1-9]    # match the leading digit, any digit other than zero
  \d{1,2}  # match between 1 and 2 digits
  ,\d{3}   # match a comma followed by 3 digits
  |        # or
  [1-9]    # match the leading digit, any digit other than zero
  \d{0,2}  # match between 0 and 2 digits
  (?:      # begin a non-capture group
    ,\d{3} # match a comma followed by 3 digits
  ){2,}    # end the non-capture group and executed it >= 2 times
)          # end the non-capture group 
$          # match the end of the string
```

---

Lastly, we can factor out the match of the leading digit.

```
^[1-9](?:\d{1,2},\d{3}|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,})$
```

Comment: You are very close, but his example `"10,400,000","10,900,000","500,000",`, doesn't work with your Regex.  Also, the order of parts divided by `|` is wrong.  Change it to `[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,}|[1-9]\d{1,2},\d{3}`, see [this](https://regex101.com/r/VEpy30/1).

Comment: @Darin, l (and @Thefourthbird) assumed the OP expected each string to represent a single number with commas, that is, strings such as `"10,400,000"`, `"10,900,000"` and `"500,000"`, not strings that contain representations of multiple numbers such as `'"10,400,000", "10,900,000", "500,000"'`. Note also that the regex you suggest matches `"50,000"` within the strings `",050,000"` and
`"50,00000"`.

Comment: `50,000` is 5 digits, and he says "at least five digits".  I don't believe go allows for look ahead or behind of any kind, but, if the numbers are quoted as he shows, then perhaps you can grab the quotes: `"(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,}|[1-9]\d{1,2},\d{3})"`

Comment: @Darin, I don't think the OP expects the string to contain quotes, but I will ask.

Answer (score 2):

You might use:

```
^(?:\d{2,3}|\d{1,3},\d{3})(?:,\d{3})+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d{2,3}` Match 2-3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `,\d{3}` Match a comma and 3 digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?:,\d{3})+` Repeat 1+ times matching `,` and 3 digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l2uTgP/1).

---

Without accepting leading zeroes, you can start the match with `[1-9]` and account for it in the following quantifier:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:,\d{3})+$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wqvx1C/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point, I have added another option to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your example `"10,400,000","10,900,000","500,000",` is typical of what you are working with, then it looks like you probably have 2 options.

1. You can get the matches that capture the double quotes with the number, see this [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z8H3J6/1).

   - `"(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,}|[1-9]\d{1,2},\d{3})"`
2. The second option depends on what can be done in the Go language.  If you can capture the groups instead of the matches, then the double quotes can be excluded, see this [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w3R8Gd/1).

   - `(?:")([1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3}){2,}|[1-9]\d{1,2},\d{3})(?:")`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, I've misunderstood the question.
Why would *"500,000"* be invalid, it has *"... at least five digits with comma on the price ..."*?

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
\"\d\d\d?(?:,\d{3})+\"
```